# When designing and coding websites, do people usually go with the "Design in Photoshop and Slice" method or is there another way?

Tags: website-design

I've seen a lot of tutorials that design the site in like Photoshop and then slice it to code it. But, that just seems like a lot to me. I've never designed it in something like Photoshop. I've always just sketched it out then coded it, only using Photoshop for certain assets like logos or header images. But, of course, I'm still a student so I'm not making super complex sites. So, I guess my question is: Is this method an efficient one or are there other ways of doing it?

Comment: This is not exactly a UX question, and I can't see any answer being consider correct.

Comment: @Izhaki while it's certainly debatable, I always argue that how a site is built (in terms of process) does play a huge role in the quality of the UX.

Comment: I can completely see where you are coming from and myself think that often questions that do not comply with the site rules are very useful for the community. But big stakes in the success of the stackexchange network belong to the reduced filtering demands from users - whether in the questions being asked, or the answers given. The question is much more appropriate to web/graphic design than to UX - it has nothing to do with users directly.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't really sure where it would go. I didn't think it would go on the graphic design site

Answer (score 3):

Old way: "design the site in like Photoshop and then slice it"

New way: "just sketch it out then code"

So, you're doing it the preferred way.

The problems with the old way were numerous:

- Those doing the PhotoShop often weren't well versed in the medium they were designing for (ie, they didn't have a clue about web browsers, CSS, HTML, web servers, etc)
- PhotoShop is an inflexible canvas. A web browser is an infinitely flexible canvas.
- Effort would be put into visual decoration of the PhotoShop objects that would have been much more efficient to handle in CSS
- there is no concept of interaction design in the context of a static JPG
- It was a waterfall process

The benefits of the new way are numerous:

- From the get go you are designing in a responsive way
- It's an iterative process (you can jump between PSD and HTML as needed to leverage the best of both)
- You will typically cut down the need for so many raster images as you can do so much with CSS now (not to mention other file formats such as SVG and Web fonts) = leaner sites = faster sites = happier customers.
- The client gets to see the 'real' site sooner than later and can react to the medium itself (rather than the facsimile that photoshop is)
- You are integrating the interaction design, visual design and content together, which will allow for a much more cohesive solution in the end.

Now, *all that said*, do people still do it the old way? Yep. And it's frustrating. But not uncommon by any means. This is especially true in large companies that outsource a lot of their development. We're still slogging through a web development process that felt out of data back in 2001...create a PSD, send it overseas, wait for the really bad markup/sloppy css/useless JavaScript to come back. *sigh*. :)

**From a UX perspective...**

To keep this on-topic with UX, I think the 'interaction design' bullet point is the most important.

UX isn't just visual design. It's visual design + interaction + content + IA + etc. In otherwords, it's the complete package.

While UX doesn't always have say as to how the database will be structured, or how the API wrapper will be implemented, we should fight to have say or even ownership of the presentation layer.

That means a UX team that is at least prototyping in HTML/CSS and JS (if we're talking web dev) will have a huge advantage over a team just sending PSD files to some other dev team. This is because that true interaction design happens when you start getting messy with code.

All of the thinking and hypothesizing and theorizing of an interaction just can't compare to doing all of that and *then implementing it* for it's when you build the actual experience that all of the nuances of an interaction that are so important come out of the woodwork. I can't say I've ever had a documented interaction actually be implemented correctly. You just can't translate interaction design into a text document for someone remote to implement.

Comment: Great answer. I'm glad I finally got this cleared up. I was going through a tutorial recently and they used the slicing method and I just could not do it. It just seemed so inefficient to me. So, I'm glad the way I've been doing it is the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

"Just sketch it out and code it" is better by far than slicing and using anything directly from Photoshop, and DA01 gave great reasons why.

I'll add, to your question about other ways of doing it, that it can be helpful to sketch it out in a graphics program that will be used to produce the actual assets. I use Illustrator, some use  Sketch, and even powerpoint (I don't suggest powerpoint).

Photoshop is not a place to make most assets, since it is inherently pixel-based. Illustrator and Sketch output assets well and give a competent design area with which to plan, duplicate, iterate, and lay things out more or less how they will actually look.

By doing this, you'll do less fine-tuning with assets, trying to make them fit in your final product. If it ever becomes more than just you doing the work, having these hi-fidelity visual compositions will provide a valuable reference for developers and designers.

Comment: Thanks! And you're right. I forgot, I usually use Illustrator for the assets; I just use Photoshop when I want to add effects to them.